# updating forms from symfony 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to update my Symfony app from 2.6.* to 2.7.* and I'm having troubles figuring out the new form system and how I should be using it.

I have a few LazyChoiceLists to load choices for some common things that multiple forms use.  Such as a list of US States.  This way, if I ever needed to change it I didn't have to dig through 20 some FormTypes and change their state values.

But in 2.7.* they seem to have done away with `choice_list` in favor of `choice_loader` or just using `choices` and passing a series of callables to modify it.

I also have one LazyChoiceList that creates a list based on files found in the system.

In short, how do I move these to the new methods?  I'm lost and can't seem to figure it out reading through the [Change Blog](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.7.0-BETA1/UPGRADE-2.7.md) and this short [tutorial blog](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization)

Here's an example of what I have currently for 2.6.*.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\ChoiceList;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

class TemplateChoice extends LazyChoiceList
{
    public function loadChoiceList()
    {
        $finder = new Finder();

        $finder->files()->in(__DIR__ . '/../../Resources/views/Emails/');

        $choices = array();

        foreach($finder as $file)
        {
            $path = $file->getRealPath();
            $parent = basename($file->getPath());
            $filename = $file->getBaseName('.twig');

            if($parent === 'Emails')
            {
                $choices[$path] = ucfirst($filename);
            }
            else
            {
                $choices[$parent][$path] = '[' . $parent . '] ' . ucfirst($filename);
            }
        }

        return new SimpleChoiceList($choices);
    }
}
```

There are some changes already made in this file, such as moving `setDefaultOptions()` to `configureOptions()`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AgentEmailType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Template Name'))
            ->add('emailType' , 'choice' , array(
                'label' => 'Template Type',
                'choices' => array(
                    'confirmation' => 'Confirmation Email',
                    'quote' => 'Quote Email'
                )
            ))
            ->add('fromAddress', 'text', array('label' => 'From Email'))
            ->add('subject', 'text', array('label' => 'Subject Line'))
            ->add('htmlTemplate' , 'choice' , array(
                'label' => 'HTML Template File',
                'choice_list' => new \AppBundle\Form\ChoiceList\TemplateChoice()
            ))
            ->add('plainTemplate' , 'choice' , array(
                'label' => 'Text Template File',
                'choice_list' => new \AppBundle\Form\ChoiceList\TemplateChoice()
            ))
            ->add('agent', 'entity' , array(
                'property' => 'name',
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Agent',
                'choices' => $options['agents']
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired('agents');

        $resolver->addAllowedTypes(array(
            'agents' => '\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection'
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\AgentEmail'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'agentEmail';
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I probably should add when this particular form is loaded this is the error I get.  At least I'm pretty confident this form is the culprit.

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\DefaultChoiceListFactory::Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\{closure}() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView, array given
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found this [bug report](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15037).  It's probably what my issue initially is.  But still, best practice would be updating these lists to be handled with the new systems rather than using deprecated tools.